# Adding a column to a data frame by calculating each value to be added

Tags: r, function, dataframe

Good evening,

I asked a question earlier and found it hard to implement the solution so I am gonna reask it in a more clear way.
I have the problem, that I want to add a column to a dataframe of daily returns of a stock. Lets say its normally distributed and I would like to add a column that contains the value at risk (hist) whose function I wrote myself. 
The restriction is that each observation should be assigned to my function and take the last 249 observations as well.
So when the next observation is calculated it should also take only the last 249 observations of the das before. So the input values should move as the time goes on. In other words I want values from 251 days ago to be excluded. Hopefully I explained myself well enough. If not maybe the code speaks for me:

```
df<- data.frame(Date=seq(ISOdate(2000,1,1), by = "days", length.out = 500), Returns=rnorm(500))
#function
VaR.hist<- function(x, n=250, hd=20, q=0.05){
  width<-nrow(x)
  NA.x<-na.omit(x)
  quantil<-quantile(NA.x[(width-249):width],probs=q)
  VaR<- quantil*sqrt(hd)%>%
    return()
}
# Run the function on the dataframe
df$VaR<- df$Returns%>%VaR.hist()

 Error in (width - 249):width : argument of length 0
```

This is the Error code that I get and not my new Variable... 
Thanks !!

Comment: You are calling your function with just a numeric vector (`df$Returns`). The first line in your function (`nrow(x)`) will return `NULL`, when `x` is a numeric vector.

Comment: Can you probably give a sample expected output of the first couple of lines? Also please use `set.seed` when you sample numbers from distributions so we can replicate the same numbers on the other end.

Comment: Hello! If sample expected output means giving you some idea of what numbers would ideally come out then it would be a vector of the 5th percentile of the loss function of the daily returns. I.e. the 5th worst return of a return series of 100 days. The solution of Mr. Schlegel gave me only 1 number repeated 500 times which is the same result that I got when I tried out other things but never really a dynamic vektor of numbers... Hope that made it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand what you want to do exactly.

My understanding is that you wish to compute a new variable `VarR`, calculated based on the current and previous 249 observations of `df$Returns`, right?

Is this about what you wish to do?:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)

df <- tibble(
  Date = seq(ISOdate(2000, 1, 1), by = "days", length.out = 500), 
  Returns=rnorm(500)
)

the_function <- function(i, mydata, hd = 20, q = .05) {
  r <- 
    mydata %>% 
    filter(ridx <= i, ridx > i - 249) %>% 
    pull(Returns)

  quantil <- quantile(r, probs = q)
  VaR <- quantil*sqrt(hd)
}

df <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(ridx = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(VaR = map_dbl(ridx, the_function, mydata = .))
```

If you are looking for a base-R solution:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(ISOdate(2000, 1, 1), by = "days", length.out = 500), 
  Returns = rnorm(500)
)


a_function <- function(i, mydata, hd = 20, q = .05) {
  r <- mydata$Returns[mydata$ridx <= i & mydata$ridx > (i - 249)] 
  quantil <- quantile(r, probs = q)
  VaR <- quantil*sqrt(hd)
}

df$ridx <- 1:nrow(df) # add index
df$VaR <- sapply(df$ridx, a_function, mydata = df)
```

Comment: Yeah you understood me 100% and thanks for giving a code example, that is actually above my current R skill level. I tried to run your code and it would return: Error in ~ridx <= i : object 'ridx' not found  . I dont understand why you rename "i" to "ridx". Could you not use the i as it is? And what does pull() mean in this function. I tried to look it up but still no clue what it is doing in the function.The mutate command should create 2 variables (Rownumber and VaR) in your example? Maybe you could say what map_dbl means. With this I hope to move on myself. Thanks again!

Comment: @Rbitrage - I've edited the code example given above, it should do the trick now. I've also added a suggested solution using base R. 

The first snippet is using `tidyverse` syntax and functions. Here's a great introduction to it: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ (`pull()` is a function within the `dplyr`-package, which is included in the `tidyverse`; see `?dplyr::pull`).

Answer (score 0):

As wibom wrote in the comment `nrow(x)` does not work for vectors. What you need is `length()` instead. Also you do not need `return()` in the last line as R automatically returns the last line of a function if there is no early `return()` before.

```
library(dplyr)
df<- data.frame(Date=seq(ISOdate(2000,1,1), by = "days", length.out = 500), Returns=rnorm(500))

#function
VaR.hist <- function(x, n=250, hd=20, q=0.05){
  width <- length(x) # here you need length as x is a vector, nrow only works for data.frames/matrixes
  NA.x <- na.omit(x)
  quantil <- quantile(NA.x[(width-249):width], probs = q)
  quantil*sqrt(hd)
}

# Run the function on the dataframe
df$VaR <- df$Returns %>% VaR.hist()
```

Comment: Hey! THanks for answering my question. I tried out your solution and it would indeed add a column of values. Unfortunately always the same number and not a dynamic number... I explained myself a lil better in the comment above. Still appreciate your work thx!